# JS Heap recommended memory size

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, heap-memory

Is there any limit to the heap size in the chrome memory profile ?

[image: heap profile]

Comment: You mean the recommended limit or the actual Chrome limit (where Chrome would crash. for instance) ?

Comment: There isn't really a limit to the heap size of a chrome memory profile, since JS itself doesn't have access to system information such as available memory.  It's up to you the developer, to identify what is the acceptable amount of memory your web application can use.

Comment: I was more interested in the 'recommended limit' for a web application. With the chrome developer tools i can see that it 35-66mb, I agree that it is up to me to work on/fix/identify, but was wondering if there is a standard 'recommended limit' for cross browser.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Note:** This is a Chrome only answer, see below why.

---

You should take a look at `window.performance.memory` in Chrome Dev Tools, there is a `jsHeapSizeLimit` attribute.
However, I'm not sure this will be the maximum value on any memory profiling y-axis

You can find more informations on MDN : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/performance

> **performance.memory** :
>
> > A non-standard extension added in Chrome.

Linked in MDN (not anymore) : https://webplatform.github.io/docs/apis/timing/properties/memory/

> #### performance.memory :
>
> Note: This property is read-only.
>
> ```
> console.log(performance.memory)
>
> // Would show, for example
> //{
> // jsHeapSizeLimit: 767557632,
> // totalJSHeapSize: 58054528,
> // usedJSHeapSize: 42930044
> //}
> ```
>
> Notes
>
> usedJsHeapSize is the total amount of memory being used by JS objects including V8 internal objects, totalJsHeapSize is current size of the JS heap including free space not occupied by any JS objects. This means that usedJsHeapSize can not be greater than totalJsHeapSize. Note that it is not necessarily that there has ever been totalJsHeapSize of alive JS objects.

See the [WebKit Patch](https://bugs.webkit.org/attachment.cgi?id=154876&action=prettypatch) for how the quantized values are exposed. The tests in particular help explain how it works.

---

Be careful, values are expressed without units because there isn't. This is because webkit does not want to expose system informations such as available memory size. It only provide a way to compare memory usage (for instace between two different versions of a website).

Comment: I have been using the chrome performance.memory and observing usedJSHeapSize vs jsHeapSizeLimit, and totalJSHeapSize vs  jsHeapSizeLimit, I think that it isn't the jsHeap being full that is slowing our application but that our call-stacks are large and unnecessarily calling the same function in the same call-stack, think this might be causing more issue. Thanks for you answer.

Comment: Glad that could help ! I didn't use this a lot yet, I just read this some weeks ago somewhere. If you find any useful ressources, let me know I will add it to my answer

Comment: In Chrome 68+ you will get non-bucketized values for scripts served from the same origin as the webpage (eTLD+1). The limit is relaxed to one sample every 50ms. This means you probably don't need `--enable-precise-memory-info` anymore.

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/7c7847f69de403f6c798dfccba10812039a60480

Comment: so what is the recommend heap size?

Comment: there is no recommendation, optimizing an app is all about finding the right trade-off between memory usage and cpu usage.

Answer (score 4):

In theory the memory limit (not LocalStorage, but actual memory) is unlimited, and only bounded by the amount of RAM on the system. In practice, most web browsers will place a limit on each window (for example, 200MB). Sometimes the limit is customizable by the user. Additionally, an operating system can put a limit on the amount of memory used by an application.

Comment: It is unclear why there are 3 values instead of just two. Any idea on this matter ? Even MDN doesn't touch this subject and the old https://webplatform.github.io/docs/apis/timing/properties/memory/ just explains about Used and Total. Therefore why is there the Limit one ? What's the difference beween Total and Limit ? If Used is some percentage from the Total, where does Limit stand ?